# How disable/enable input using condition?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Until a few days ago I thought that **Pinescript Inputs** were **not** conditional, in fact it is not possible to do something like this.

```
bool_x = input.bool(true, "On")

if bool_x
  integer_x = input.int(0, 'lenght', minval=1)
else
  // Do nothing. Don't create this input
```

That's not possible 'cause inputs use **Constant** and they cannot be changed.

However i found a script created by a user and i dont know how he did a similar thing, how can i **disable** an input in the same way he did based on condition?

Here the indicator's name (We cannot see the source code): ***Session Volume Profile HD***

[image: Example of what i'm taliking about]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Session Volume Profile HD*** is an indicator published by Tradingview. Naturally, Tradingview has superpowers that we do not have :)

In short, you cannot do that at the moment in pinescript.

As a workaround, you can have a `bool` input to enable/disable a specific input but it won't disable other inputs. You just need to programmatically ignore the other inputs.

Comment: Well, in fact I thought it was (for now) impossible. Thank you for the confirmation Vitruvius. However it would be useful if they implemented this function together with the possibility to change the options of an input conditionally. =)